# WPF -> WinForms interop in BackEnd / FrontEnd behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on an application where I have a WPF front-end and a back-end both written in C#. The back-end is fully made with MVVM, but due to legacy reasons I still have to use old WinForms controls.

For that reason I wrote a wrapper that contain the WinForms control in the back-end and renders its result and transfer the image to the front-end.

The front-end is a plain WPF control that simply takes the Bitmap and draws it onto its render surface.

The only problem is, that event from the front-end are not delegated to the back-end - of course. I therefore intercepted the WndProc from the front-end control and delegated the messages from the front-end to the back-end by the native WinAPI call SendMessage.

Although everything works fine, the interesting thing is, that although I have not intercepted the mouse up event I get the Mouseup event from the control ( I really don't send a WM_MOUSEUP message). This seems to be a bit magic to me and I don't understand where the MouseUp comes from. Also MouseMove events get through if the left mouse button is pressed.

Attached is some demo code, maybe not fully working because the XAML code is missing:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ChartDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //   Chart myChart;
        BackEndControl Control;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //         myChart = new Chart();
            //         myChart.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            //         myChart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            //         ChartArea area = new ChartArea();

            //         myChart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

            //         Series aSeries = new Series();
            //         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) aSeries.Points.AddXY(i, i);

            //         myChart.Series.Add(aSeries);

            System.Windows.Forms.Button aControl = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            aControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;



            aControl.MouseUp += aControl_MouseUp;
            aControl.MouseDown += aControl_MouseDown;
            aControl.MouseMove += aControl_MouseMove;


            Control = new BackEndControl(aControl);
            Content = Control;
        }

        private void aControl_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MouseMove");
        }

        private void aControl_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MouseDown");
        }

        private void aControl_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MouseUp");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Back-End Control that wraps native WinForm controls and delegates
    /// events back and forth.
    /// </summary>
    public class BackEndControl : Control, IDisposable
    {
        HwndSource source;
        BitmapSource ScreenCapture;
        System.Drawing.Bitmap WindowBitmap;


        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the associated native WinForms control.
        /// </summary>
        System.Windows.Forms.Control Control;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of BackEndControl.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control"></param>
        public BackEndControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
        {
            Contract.Requires(control != null);

            Control = control;
            Control.CreateControl();
            Control.Invalidated += Control_Invalidated;

            Loaded += BackEndControl_Loaded;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// dtor
        /// </summary>
        ~BackEndControl()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Associate the 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void BackEndControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the initial size to the control.
            Control.Size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight);

            source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);

            // Remove the handler again, since there are problems in the Finalizer running in a different finalizer thread
            // and the event can onmly be unhooked in the current thread.
            Loaded -= BackEndControl_Loaded;
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public enum WndMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_SIZE = 0x0005,
            WM_SIZING = 0x0214,

            WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Native MessageProc to intercept native window messages to the WPF control
        /// and forward the messages to the original WinForms control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
        /// <param name="msg"></param>
        /// <param name="wParam"></param>
        /// <param name="lParam"></param>
        /// <param name="handled"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {

            if (hwnd == source.Handle)
            {
                // Forward only certain messages to the backend winforms control.
                switch ((WndMessages)msg)
                {
                    case WndMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                        Console.WriteLine(msg);
                        return SendMessage(Control.Handle, msg, wParam, lParam);

                    case WndMessages.WM_SIZING:
                        Console.WriteLine("PAINT");
                        InvalidateVisual();
                        break;

                    case WndMessages.WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
                        Console.WriteLine("EXIT");
                        Control.Size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight);
                        break;
                }
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event-Handler for invalidate events on the control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void Control_Invalidated(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.InvalidateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Control.Size.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (WindowBitmap != null)
                {
                    if (Control.Size != WindowBitmap.Size)
                    {
                        WindowBitmap.Dispose();
                        WindowBitmap = null;
                    }
                }

                if (WindowBitmap == null)
                {
                    WindowBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                }

                Control.DrawToBitmap(WindowBitmap, Control.ClientRectangle);

                ScreenCapture = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                   WindowBitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                   BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(WindowBitmap.Width, WindowBitmap.Height));

            }

            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update the view.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="drawingContext"></param>
        protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);

            if (ScreenCapture != null)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawImage(ScreenCapture, new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
            }
        }

        #region IDisposable

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets if the object has been disposed either by Dispose() or by the Finalizer.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsDisposed
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the allocated resources.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the allocated resources.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing"></param>
        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!IsDisposed)
            {
                IsDisposed = true;
                ScreenCapture = null;

                if (source != null)
                {
                    source.RemoveHook(WndProc);
                    source.Dispose();
                    source = null;
                }

                if (WindowBitmap != null)
                {
                    WindowBitmap.Dispose();
                    WindowBitmap = null;
                }

                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.Invalidated -= Control_Invalidated;

                    Control.Dispose();
                    Control = null;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

What could be the problem/magic that the events pass through?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: In order to by pass all the other messages, shouldn't you need to set `handled = true;` in your `WndProc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. It seems that although the control is invisible it still gets the capture and therefore all mouse events are going to the control. In a situation where I have a real front-end/back-end it works fine. If I have the front-end/back-end on the same machine it doesn't work. I'll dig a little deeper to find a possible solution and will then post it here.